# Adding a third function to IIFE

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a third function to this code:

```
var fn3 = (function() {
  var first = true;
  return function() {
    first ? fn1() : fn2();
    first = !first;
  }
})();

function fn1() {
console.log(1);
};
function fn2() {
console.log(2);
};

----

<button onClick="fn3()">click</button>
```

I tried adding `fn3()` and changing the var to something else but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Could anyone please help me? Thank you :)

Comment: It really isn't clear what you've tried (you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your *problem*, not just some working code which doesn't do what you want it to do) or what you want the code to do.

Comment: "it doesn't work": Please elaborate.  For example, what was it *supposed* to do?

Comment: FWIW, a better way to present your question would be to ask "How can I alternate between three functions on click" or something like that. That would better express what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am sorry, it does seem a bit ambiguous.
I would like to have this code run three separate functions. I added function fn3() { console.log(3); }; and changed the var name to fn4. The problem here is that the ternary option does not allow for three conditions?

Comment: it's working for me. It is printing `1` as `first` is true

Comment: to toggle the `boolean` move ` var first = true;` out of `fun3()`

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu: No, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the functions in an array and use an index for getting the next function.

```js
function fn1() {
    console.log(1);
}

function fn2() {
    console.log(2);
}

function fn3() {
    console.log(3);
}

var next = (function(array) {
    var index = -1;
    return function() {
        return array[index = (index + 1) % 3]();
    };
})([fn1, fn2, fn3]);
```

```html
<button onClick="next()">click</button>
```

Comment: The array can be stored along side `index` as well.